# drawRect at double the size

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

If I override `drawRect` in order to display an image and place a dinamically-generated overlay on it (see code), whenever I scale up the image it is drawn in a very blurry way as the result of the scaling.

The image is composed of two pieces, an image drawn from a png (whose original size is 2x the wanted one, so it should not give problems when scaled, but it does) and the other is dinamically generated according to the rect size, so it should also adapt to the current rect size, but it doesn't.

Any help?

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height), [UIImage imageNamed:@"actionBg.png"].CGImage);

    // generate the overlay
    if ([self isActive] == NO && self.fullDelay != 0) { // TODO: remove fullDelay check!
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);
        CGContextRef overlayCtx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        int segmentSize = (rect.size.height / [self fullDelay]);

        for (int i=0; i<[self fullDelay]; i++) {
            float alpha = 0.9 - (([self fullDelay] * 0.1) - (i * 0.1));
            [[UIColor colorWithRed:120.0/255.0 green:14.0/255.0 blue:14.0/255.0 alpha:alpha] setFill];

            if (currentDelay > i) {
                CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, i * segmentSize, rect.size.width, segmentSize);
                CGContextFillRect(overlayCtx, r);
            }
            [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.3] setFill];
            CGRect line = CGRectMake(0, (i * segmentSize) + segmentSize - 1 , rect.size.width, 1);
            CGContextFillRect(overlayCtx, line);
        }

        UIImage *overlay = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIImage *overlayMasked = [TDUtilities maskImage:overlay withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"actionMask.png"]];

        // prevent the drawings to be flipped
        CGContextTranslateCTM(overlayCtx, 0, rect.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(overlayCtx, 1.0, -1.0);

        CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, rect, overlayMasked.CGImage);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeNormal);

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are drawing `overlayMasked` as a CGImage with `CGContextDrawImage`, which knows nothing of scale. Either you will have to double the size yourself manually if you're in a double-scale situation, or you should use UIImage, which knows about scale.